# JQuery convert string to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, href

I have 3 select fields, and the combined value of these I would like to use as a extra part of an url.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<select name="cos" id="cos" size="5">
  <option value="/squad">Squad</option>
  <option value="/class">Class</option>
 </select>
<select name="color" id="color" size="5">
  <option value="/purpleblack">PurpleBlack</option>
  <option value="/redblack">RedBlack</option>
  <option value="/aquablack">AquaBlack</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year" size="5">
  <option value="/1984">1984</option>
  <option value="/1985">1985</option>
  <option value="/1986">1986</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$("select").change(function () { 
   var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('name');
       str += $(this).attr('value');             
       });
      $("div#output").text(str);
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eZKUU/264/

Right now it's working.. after I select an option in all 3 of the `selectfields` I get an output like `/squad/redblack/1985`.
I would like to use this output in an url, so it would look like:

`mysite.com/squad/redblack/1985`

Is there an easy way of doing this? And also.. To only get the link visible after all three of the `selectfields` have an option selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if the number of selected options is the same amount as the number of `select` elements.

```js
var selectedAllLength = $("select").length;
$("select").change(function () {
   var str = location.origin;
    var selected = $("select option:selected");
    var selectedCount = selected.length;
    if(selectedCount == selectedAllLength) {
        selected.each(
            function () {
                str += $(this).attr('value');             
            }
        );
        $("#output").html('<a href=' + str + '>The link is here</a>');
    }
})
.trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cos" id="cos" size="5">
  <option value="/squad">Squad</option>
  <option value="/class">Class</option>
 </select>
<select name="color" id="color" size="5">
  <option value="/purpleblack">PurpleBlack</option>
  <option value="/redblack">RedBlack</option>
  <option value="/aquablack">AquaBlack</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year" size="5">
  <option value="/1984">1984</option>
  <option value="/1985">1985</option>
  <option value="/1986">1986</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following. Add an `a` element and keep it hidden until is completed. Update `a` element `href` attribute with selected options:

```js
$("select").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).parent().attr('name');
      str += $(this).attr('value');
      //update href with selected values
      $("#mySite").attr("href", "mysite.com/" + str);
    });
    //keep anchor element hidden until all three options is selected
    $("#mySite").toggle($("#cos").find("option:selected").length > 0 && $("#color").find("option:selected").length > 0 && $("#year").find("option:selected").length > 0);
    $("div#output").text(str);
  })
  .trigger('change');
```

```css
#mySite {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cos" id="cos" size="5">
  <option value="/squad">Squad</option>
  <option value="/class">Class</option>
</select>
<select name="color" id="color" size="5">
  <option value="/purpleblack">PurpleBlack</option>
  <option value="/redblack">RedBlack</option>
  <option value="/aquablack">AquaBlack</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year" size="5">
  <option value="/1984">1984</option>
  <option value="/1985">1985</option>
  <option value="/1986">1986</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
<a id="mySite" href="#">Redirect Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To only get the link after all three have been selected, simply use an `if` statement to only generate and display the link if 3 options are selected. To make it a URL, just append the path you get to the base URL. Something like:

```
$("select").change(function () { 
  var str = "";
  if(#("select option:selected").length === 3){
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
      var id = $(this).parent().attr('name');
      str += $(this).attr('value');             
    });
    $("div#output").text("mysite.com" + str);
    // Or, if you want a clickable link and not just a URL:
    // $("div#output").append($("<a>").attr({href: "mysite.com" + str}).append("Click me"));
  }
})
.trigger('change');
```